# How i can insert "%" symbol in my writing context?

Tags: editors

while writing % in the sentence it is considering as a comment . Just like i wana write this sentence **25% of this bottle is empty.** But texnic does not showing remaining text in the output. 
kindly give me some suggestion .
Regards

Comment: write it as `25\%`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Well, as you should know, the % symbol is an special symbol reserved in `TeX` for comment a line of code before that symbol. If you want to use it inside your text you should add a `\` before, i.e. type `\%`. Try to type `25 \%` for your example.

Answer (score 2):

In case you have a lot of physical quantities, use the [`siunitx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\SI{25}{\percent} of this bottle is empty.

\end{document}
```

[image: output]